# Php array to loop though array key and value

Tags: javascript, php, html

Here is the scenario, I have an HTML form with a checkbox which receive an array of value on check and I gave it a name attributes (day) with this same checkbox is another input element that receive array of value for it name attribute (time_slot). I used javascript for adding and deleting extract input field add.

```
........ Monday .............
// first input form
   <input type="checkbox" style="width: 20px" value = "monday" class="checkbox form-control" name="day[]" />
                    
<script>
 $(document).ready(function() {
  var max  = 10; //maximum input boxes allowed
  var container = $(".wraper_time_slot_monday");  
  var add = document.getElementById("add_icon_time_slot_monday");
  var x = 1; 
    $(add).click(function(e){ e.preventDefault();
        if(x < max){ 
            x++;
            $(container).append('<div><input  type="time" name="time_slot[]" style="width:150px;margin-right:10px; margin-bottom:10px; color: black; height:40px; border: 1px solid #D3D3D3; border-radius: 4px; cursor: pointer;"/><a href="#" class="delete"><span class="btn btn-round btn-danger  btn-xs" ><i class="fa fa-minus" ></i></span><b style="padding-left:10px;">Delete Slot</b></a></div>'); //adding new input field
        }
    });
   
    $(container).on("click",".delete", function(e){ //user click on remove text
        e.preventDefault(); $(this).parent('div').remove(); x--;
    })
});
 </script>

// second input for 
   <input type="time" name="time_slot[]">  
 
.......... Tuesday ........                
// first input form
   <input type="checkbox" style="width: 20px" value = "tuesday" class="checkbox form-control" name="day[]" />
                    
<script>
 $(document).ready(function() {
  var max  = 10; //maximum input boxes allowed
  var container = $(".wraper_time_slot_tuesday");  
  var add = document.getElementById("add_icon_time_slot_tuesday");
  var x = 1; 
    $(add).click(function(e){ e.preventDefault();
        if(x < max){ 
            x++;
            $(container).append('<div><input  type="time" name="time_slot[]" style="width:150px;margin-right:10px; margin-bottom:10px; color: black; height:40px; border: 1px solid #D3D3D3; border-radius: 4px; cursor: pointer;"/><a href="#" class="delete"><span class="btn btn-round btn-danger  btn-xs" ><i class="fa fa-minus" ></i></span><b style="padding-left:10px;">Delete Slot</b></a></div>'); //adding new input field
        }
    });
   
    $(container).on("click",".delete", function(e){ //user click on remove text
        e.preventDefault(); $(this).parent('div').remove(); x--;
    })
});
 </script>

// second input for 
   <input type="time" name="time_slot[]">
```

I want to be able to get array of all value for each value Monday and Tuesday as shown so I can easily insert into database row each time and it days see since below. For instance if two times were added into the array for monday then It should insert as

```
   Day     |    Time
  monday   |    1:00am
  monday   |    2:30am
```

And tuesday will be as below:

```
   Day      |    Time
  tuesday   |    3:00am
  tuesday   |    5:30am
```

SO I am trying to use PHP to loop through so I can get the number of time_slot for monday and time_slot for tuesday respectively but the issue with below code is that I am not able separate add slot for monday from tuesday, the array just just show all arrays inside `time_slot[]`. I need the information in such a way that I can use for loop to insert each time slot as per it day.

```
        $res = [];
            $res['day'] = $_POST['day'];
            $res['time_slot'] = $_POST['time_slot'];
            
            
           $keys = array_keys($res);
for($i = 0; $i < count($res); $i++) {
    echo $keys[$i] . "{<br>";
    foreach($res[$keys[$i]] as $key => $value) {
        echo $value . "<br>";
    }
    echo "}<br>";
}
```

So with the above the result is :

```
day{
monday
tuesday
}
time_slot{
22:19
11:20
13:22
13:22
14:23
}
```

and I was expecting a result like below:

```
['monday']=>['22:19']
['monday']=>['11:20']
['monday']=>['13:22']
['tuesday']=>['13:22']
['tuesday']=>['14:23']
```

Comment: Where is the PHP code you have problems with?

Comment: I just edited it with my PHP code

Comment: It is not clear for me what your expected result is. Please show us what `var_export($_POST);` is and an example of your expected result.

Comment: This makes it impossible to see which times belong to which day. Also you can not have arrays having the same key multiple times.

Comment: Have distinct names and not `time_slot[]` for everything.

Answer (score 0):

I want able to solve this by giving each day it distinct name and use implode to upload the array of time slot and explode to get them into array where I need to use them.

I changed `day[]` above to `day_monday` and `day_tuesday` then also `time_slot[]` to `time_slot_monday` and `day_tuesday` for monday and tuesday respectively.

Then in my PHP I simply use implode to get values of the array of each `time_slot[]` as below:

```
 $day_monday = $_POST['day_monday'];
            $time_slot_monday = implode(',',$_POST['time_slot_monday']);
  $day_tuesday = $_POST['day_tuesday'];
            $time_slot_tuesday = implode(',',$_POST['time_slot_tuesday']);
```